# Add Same Key To Underordered Map

Tags: c++, hash, hashmap

i have data like this;

```
a - 5
b - 4
c - 3
d - 4
a - 7
b - 3
```

I insert that data to map in **C++** like this;

```
unordered_map<string, int> umap;
umap["a"] = 5;
umap["b"] = 4;
umap["c"] = 3;
umap["d"] = 4;
umap["a"] = 7;
umap["b"] = 3;
```

**I want to add values to same key if exist the key.**

Expected output;

```
a - 12
b - 7
c - 3
d - 4
```

How can i do this merge(i am not sure that is true word or not) operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to use `+=` instead of `=`.  When you first create a onbject in the map using

```
umap["a"]
```

then the mapped value is zero initialized so the map contains

```
{{"a", 0}}
```

Doing `umap["a"] += 5` would then give you

```
{{"a", 5}}
```

If you then did `umap["a"] += 7;` then the map would have

```
{{"a", 12}}
```

So doing that to all of the elements you get:

```
unordered_map<string, int> umap;
umap["a"] += 5;
umap["b"] += 4;
umap["c"] += 3;
umap["d"] += 4;
umap["a"] += 7;
umap["b"] += 3;
```

and the map will have

```
{{"a", 12}, {"b", 7}, {"c", 3}, {"d", 4}}
```

Comment: @OSentrk There is no complexity change.  `umap["a"]` returns a reference to the mapped value so you are just applying `+=` to that value instead of `=`.